# Datatable submit using submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, jeditable

I have a datatable and one of the coloumns is editable( using jeditable plugin) . So now i need a common submit button which will submit the entire changes. 
Here is my datatable entry.

```
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#jtable').html( '<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="pretty" id="edit_table"></table>' );
            $("#edit_table").dataTable({
                "aaData": {{ result | safe }},
                "aLengthMenu" : 100,
                "aaSorting": [],
                "aoColumns" : [
                    {'sTitle' : 'Options' },
                    {'sTitle' : 'Values'}
                ],
                "iDisplayLength": -1,
                "bFilter" : false,
                "bSearchable" :false,
                "bInfinite" :true,
                "bSort" :false,
                "bPaginate": false
            });
          $('#edit_table tbody td:eq(3),td:eq(5),td:eq(7)').editable( 'Reschedule.html',{
                "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
                    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
                    oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0] );
                },
                "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
                    return {
                        "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                        "column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
                    };
                }
            } );
        } );
```

So i need a common submit button to submit the data on the table. I have to update the data to   DB using python. ( I am using python + flask frame work).  Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you show some of the html? is this table wrapped in a <form>?

Comment: <body>
<form name="mainform" method="get,post">
    <div id="jtable"></div>
</form>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

I'm yet to use Python to handle forms, so the information here may be wrong, however I hope it is of some use.

Your html form should only have one method, either get or post, not both. Post is more secure. Also you should use an action, and point it to your .py file that will handle the posted data. action="myPy.py"

You can also create a generic button and provide an onclick function to do something else before submitting the form. For example..

html part:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit Form" class="btn_submit" onclick="submitOrder()" />
```

alternatively you could use a submit button "input type='submit'..." and then use jQuery to call a function first before submitting, e.g.

```
$('#yourFormID').submit(function(e) {
//prevent default submit action        
e.preventDefault();
//run your function instead
submitOrder();
});
```

I also found an article about form submission using Python, it may be of help to you... 
http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms